# PySpark parquet file overwriting after transformation

Tags: sql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rdd, parquet

I'm trying to make transformations (union two tables, or add a column) in parquet file then save it, while running into FileNotFound Error.

The snippet to reproduce my error is the following:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
import pandas as pd

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('test').getOrCreate()

# create some data
a = spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame({
    'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y':[1, 2, 3]
}))
a.write.mode('overwrite').parquet('./a')

# make some transformation onto the data
a = spark.read.parquet('./a')
b = spark.read.parquet('./a')
# such as Union, and the same error replacing the following by spark.sql()
c = a.union(b).withColumn('id', monotonically_increasing_id())
c.show()

# overwrite (WHERE I got the FileNotFound error)
# one can see the parquet-xxxxxx.snappy.parquet got suppressed when overwrite
c.write.mode('overwrite').parquet('./a')
```

The error:

> Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage
> failure: Task 2 in stage 105.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure:
> Lost task 2.0 in stage 105.0 (TID 265) (suweiguodembp.home executor
> driver): java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:
> /data-xxx-xxxxxxx.snappy.parquet

My goal is to modify some lines in data for a new application. But why it can't do union or  insert columns? What is the correct way to append records for parquet files

Comment: I believe you tried to overwrite the another dataset with the dataset you've created.

Avoid writing and just read and combine then overwrite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The philosophy of spark is 'not to overwrite the data'. The very first thing `mode('overwrite')` would do is delete the path. And since you're using the **same** path, you'd lost your data before rewriting it. You'll want to make transformation and write to another place (`./temp` for example) and further use the 'cleaned' data at the new place. (Even though you need) you move it back to the original place (`./a`) from another place.

Comment: Got you. I have a performance concern: If my dataset is too big, I need to 'copy/rewrite' the whole dataset? Is there another more efficient way? Like inplace adding columns or rows using parquet?

Comment: That's why usually they make one space is **raw** and another space called **processed**, so you don't mix them together. And whenever you consume data from **processed**, you know for sure data is good and clean

Comment: ok got you it make sense! thanks